# Kusto - Adding a column to an existing materialized view

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, materialized-views

I would like to add a column to an existing Materialized View in Kusto.
In this example I am using the table **test2**

```
.create-merge table test2 (myid:int, mydate:datetime, myval:int) with (folder = "test/z001uw6n")  

.create  materialized-view  with ( lookback=time(5.00:00:00),docString='test') test_view2 on table test2 
{ test2
    | summarize take_any(1) by myid, mydate 
}
```

Now I am trying to add a column **myval**:

```
.alter  materialized-view  with ( lookback=time(5.00:00:00),docString='test') test_view2 on table test2 
{ test2
    | summarize take_any(1) by myid, mydate, myval
}
```

> However, I get an exception: Cannot create materialized view 'test_view2': .alter materialized-view does not support changing group-by expressions. Current: 'myid, mydate', New: 'myid, mydate, myval'.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-alter)
, I expected that this is possible. Do you know how to add a column ?

Comment: The link for the documentation is wrong

Answer (score 1):

See limitations in the [same link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-alter#alter-materialized-view-limitations) you referred to:

`* Changes to the materialized view group by expressions aren't supported.`

Comment: thanks for your quick answer Yifat

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-alter#alter-materialized-view-limitations) clearly states:

> Changes to the materialized view group by expressions aren't supported.